# how to access objects value by key name

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have tried every combination of x.y, x['y'], x.y.z, x['y'].z that I can think of, but I cannot for the life of me access the value of an objects value in an array by the key name. Here is what is returned from the SQL query:

```
parseMissionData:  {record: Array(1), code: 1}
    code: 1
    record: Array(1)
        0: alt: 45
        attribute: Array(6)
            0: {name: "messageCode", value: "10"}
            1: {name: "gpsFix", value: "2"}
            2: {name: "autonomous", value: "0"}
            3: {name: "lowBattery", value: "1"}
            4: {name: "intervalChange", value: "30"}
            5: {name: "resetDetected", value: "0"}
            length: 6
        __proto__: Array(0)
        azimuth: 0
        datetime: "2018-03-24T20:10:00.000Z"
        devid: "300434060496300"
        lat: 37.335394620895386
        lon: -121.82005405426025
        speed: 0
        __proto__: Object
            length: 1
        __proto__: Array(0)
        __proto__: Object
....
```

I am not guaranteed that the attributes will always be returned in the same order, so I can't assume that attribute[0] will always be the messageCode attribute. What I'm trying to test the value of is the messageCode attribute so I can key off of its value. I've tried

```
response.record[i].attribute['messageCode']
response.record[i].attribute.message.value
response.record[i].attribute['messageCode'].value
```

and a bunch of other permutations. Is there a way to directly access the attribute with the name 'messageCode' or do I have to iterate through the array
attributes and look for a match to the name value?

Update. I have tried the suggestion from Mathias247 and the code now looks like this:

```
          function parseMissionData( response ) {
            console.log('parseMissionData: ', response);
            var codeAttribute;
            for ( var i=0; i < response.record.length; i++ )
              codeAttribute = response.record[i].attribute.find(elem => elem.name == "messageCode");
              console.log('messageCode: ', codeAttribute );
              //console.log('codeAttribute: ', codeAttribute);
              //console.log('imei via find: ', response.record[i].find(elem => elem.name == "devid"))
              console.log('imei direct: ', response.record[i].devid);
          }
```

With the updated code, I can now see the value of messageCode like I was hoping. But the bizarre thing is now my reference to imei (response.record[i].devid) is broken and returns an undefined! If I comment out the find(elem =>...) for messageCode, the response.record[i].devid reference works fine. I obviously don't understand how referencing something using find can break a reference that used to work. Can someone please help to understand the interworkings here?

```
    messageCode:  {name: "messageCode", value: "10"}
 jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'devid' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'devid' of undefined
     at parseMissionData (http://localhost:3000/js/controller.js:1036:67)
     at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/js/controller.js:1021:17)
     at j (http://localhost:3000/js/jquery.min.js:2:29948)
     at k (http://localhost:3000/js/jquery.min.js:2:30262) undefined
```

Now it gets me more confused. If I order my console logs like this:

```
          function parseMissionData( response ) {
            console.log('parseMissionData: ', response);
            var codeAttribute;
            for ( var i=0; i < response.record.length; i++ )
            console.log('imei direct: ', response.record[i].devid);
            codeAttribute = response.record[i].attribute.find(elem => elem.name == "messageCode");
              console.log('messageCode: ', codeAttribute );
              //console.log('codeAttribute: ', codeAttribute);
              //console.log('imei via find: ', response.record[i].find(elem => elem.name == "devid"))
         }
```

If I log the response.record[i].imei first, it outputs fine, but codeAttribute now logs

```
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'attribute' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'attribute' of undefined
    at parseMissionData (http://localhost:3000/js/controller.js:1033:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/js/controller.js:1021:17)
    at j (http://localhost:3000/js/jquery.min.js:2:29948)
    at k (http://localhost:3000/js/jquery.min.js:2:30262) undefined
```

If I reverse the order of the logs, attribute prints fine but now imei logs an undefined error.  I must be doing something wrong, but can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

Comment: It almost looks like `record` is both an array and an object... which is weird

Answer (score 3):

> do I have to iterate through the array attributes and look for a match to the name value?

Yes, but you can use the array prototype function `find` to find the relevant entry easily. E.g.

```
let codeAttribute = response.record[i].attribute.find(elem => elem.name == "messageCode")
// codeAttribute.value === '10'
```

Comment: when I try that, I get a syntax error:<br>: Lexical declaration cannot appear in a single-statement context

Comment: Which browser? If it's an old variant, it might not understand lambda expressions? The you would `need attribute.find(function(elem) { return elem.name == "messageCode"; });`
Otherwise no idea what might be wrong on your side without further code

Comment: @cpeddie don't just expect provided code to work in _any_ context. You can't declare a variable as a single statement within a `for` or `while` loop, nor would it make any sense if you could.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreated ypur issue as below and was able to get the values of both "messageCode" and "devid". Can you let me know what exactly causes you the issue:

```
a= {name: "messageCode", value: "10"}
b ={name: "gpsFix", value: "2"}
c = {name: "autonomous", value: "0"}
d = {name: "lowBattery", value: "1"}
e = {name: "intervalChange", value: "30"}
f = {name: "resetDetected", value: "0"}


attribute = [a,b,c,d,e,f]



record = { attribute, azimuth: '0', datetime: "2018-03-24T20:10:00.000Z", devid: "300434060496300",lat: '37.335394620895386'}
parseMissionData =  {record, code: 1}

console.log(parseMissionData);

console.log(parseMissionData.record.attribute.find(o => o.name === 'messageCode').value);
console.log(parseMissionData.record.devid)
```

Comment: Didn't want to waste anymore time on this, so I just wrote a small function to iterate thru the attributes array and return the value of a key match.